# create file with text and image in Android

Tags: android, android-file

is there a way to create a file in Android in which I can add text as well as append an image at the end using FileOutputStream which I can on my device? 
what file extension should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a html file from your content.

Answer (score 0):

You can create html or add meta-tags to image file.